# Missing visible-** and hidden-** in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap v3 I often use the hidden-** classes combined with clearfix to control multi column layouts at different screen widths. For example,

I could combine multiple hidden-** in one DIV to make my multi columns appear correctly at different screen widths.

As an example if I wanted to display rows of product photos, 4 per row on larger screen sizes, 3 on smaller screens, then 2 on very small screens. The product photos might be different heights so I need the clearfix to ensure the row breaks properly.

Here's an example in v3...

http://jsbin.com/tosebayode/edit?html,css,output

Now that v4 has done away with these classes, and replaced them with the visible/hidden-**-up/down classes I seem to have to do the same thing with multiple DIVs instead.

Here's a similar example in v4...

http://jsbin.com/sagowihowa/edit?html,css,output

So I've gone from single DIVs to having to add multiple DIVs with lots of up/down classes to achieve the same thing.

From...

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block"></div>
```

to...

```
<div class="clearfix hidden-sm-up"></div>
<div class="clearfix hidden-md-up hidden-xs-down"></div>
<div class="clearfix hidden-md-down"></div>
```

Is there a better way of doing this in v4 that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 953, accepted):

**Update for Bootstrap 5 (2021)**

Bootstrap 5 has a new **xxl breakpoint**. Therefore [display classes](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/) have a new tier to support this:

Hidden only on xxl: `d-xxl-none`
Visible only on xxl: `d-none d-xxl-block`

**Bootstrap 4 (2018)**

The `hidden-*` and `visible-*` classes ***no longer exist*** in Bootstrap 4. If you want to hide an element on specific tiers or breakpoints in Bootstrap 4, use the `d-*` [**display classes**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) accordingly.

Remember that extra-small/mobile (formerly `xs`) is the default (implied) breakpoint, unless overridden by a *larger* breakpoint. Therefore, **the `-xs` infix no longer exists in Bootstrap 4**.

Show/hide for **breakpoint and down**:

- `hidden-xs-down (hidden-xs)` = `d-none d-sm-block`
- `hidden-sm-down (hidden-sm hidden-xs)` = `d-none d-md-block`
- `hidden-md-down (hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs)` = `d-none d-lg-block`
- `hidden-lg-down` = `d-none d-xl-block`
- `hidden-xl-down` (n/a 3.x) = `d-none` (same as `hidden`)

Show/hide for **breakpoint and up**:

- `hidden-xs-up` = `d-none` (same as `hidden`)
- `hidden-sm-up` = `d-sm-none`
- `hidden-md-up` = `d-md-none`
- `hidden-lg-up` = `d-lg-none`
- `hidden-xl-up` (n/a 3.x) = `d-xl-none`

Show/hide **only for a single breakpoint**:

- `hidden-xs` (only) = `d-none d-sm-block` (same as `hidden-xs-down`)
- `hidden-sm` (only) = `d-block d-sm-none d-md-block`
- `hidden-md` (only) = `d-block d-md-none d-lg-block`
- `hidden-lg` (only) = `d-block d-lg-none d-xl-block`
- `hidden-xl` (n/a 3.x) = `d-block d-xl-none`
- `visible-xs` (only) = `d-block d-sm-none`
- `visible-sm` (only) = `d-none d-sm-block d-md-none`
- `visible-md` (only) = `d-none d-md-block d-lg-none`
- `visible-lg` (only) = `d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none`
- `visible-xl` (n/a 3.x) = `d-none d-xl-block`

[Demo of the responsive display classes in Bootstrap 4](https://www.codeply.com/go/bRlHp8MxtJ)

**Also,** note that `d-*-block` can be replaced with **`d-*-inline`**, **`d-*-flex`**, **`d-*-table-cell`**, **`d-*-table`** etc.. depending on the display type of the element. Read more on the [display classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

Comment: I spotted this change when the beta was released and I think this is much better than how it was in the alpha releases. Thanks for adding the answer - I will mark as the solution.

Comment: @johna it's worse - though. There is no `d-initial` so you can no longer override the `d-<breakpoint>-hidden` and set it to its initial value. If I want to hide an element on smaller screens yet show it on medium and larger ones without knowing the initial display (which could be dynamic) then I can't restore its value. They didn't think of any of this.

Comment: @ThomasYates I don't really understand that use case. The initial display prop value is based on HTML/CSS defaults for the element (block, inline, table, etc..).

Comment: @ZimSystem here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23670 - still no solution, sadly.

Comment: thank you for the conversion table. The new logic makes zero sense: display-small-none - I would expect it to mean exactly hidden-sm (i.e. diplay: none on small devices...) huh.

Comment: Any ideas how best to use this new system alongside .row which uses display: flex; -- the display: block!important of .d-lg-block overrides the row functionality. (EDIT: Answered own question - can use: d-lg-flex)

Comment: How do you use this to hide certain table columns?

Comment: @ErikThiart As explained in the answer: `d-*-table-cell`, `d-*-table-row`, `d-*-table`, etc...

Comment: Worst update ever. How does one go from a super-intuitive "speaking" concept to something that cryptic? Opening an issue for this. They could have at least let the old classes co-exist.

Comment: I'm actually surprised at how hard it was to find this answer.

Comment: As is described in [grid-system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#grid-system), every tier has been bumped up one level. Would `visible-md` be `d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none`?

Comment: This seems to work for inline elements you want to show on small (sm) and up:
`.d-sm-inline { display: none !important; }  @media (min-width: 768px) {  .d-sm-inline { display: inline !important; } }`

Expand as needed for other breakpoints

Answer (score 45):

Unfortunately all classes `hidden-*-up` and `hidden-*-down` were removed from Bootstrap (as of Bootstrap Version **4 Beta**, in Version **4 Alpha** and Version **3** these classes still existed).

Instead, new classes `d-*` should be used, as mentioned here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities

I found out that the new approach is less useful under some circumstances. The old approach was to *HIDE* elements while the new approach is to *SHOW* elements. Showing elements is not that easy with CSS since you need to know if the element is displayed as block, inline, inline-block, table etc.

You might want to restore the former "hidden-*" styles known from Bootstrap 3 with this CSS:

```
/*\
 * Restore Bootstrap 3 "hidden" utility classes.
\*/

/* Breakpoint XS */
@media (max-width: 575px)
{
    .hidden-xs-down, .hidden-sm-down, .hidden-md-down, .hidden-lg-down, .hidden-xl-down, 
    .hidden-xs-up, 
    .hidden-unless-sm, .hidden-unless-md, .hidden-unless-lg, .hidden-unless-xl
    {
        display: none !important;
    }

}

/* Breakpoint SM */
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px)
{
    .hidden-sm-down, .hidden-md-down, .hidden-lg-down, .hidden-xl-down, 
    .hidden-xs-up, .hidden-sm-up, 
    .hidden-unless-xs, .hidden-unless-md, .hidden-unless-lg, .hidden-unless-xl
    {
        display: none !important;
    } 
}

/* Breakpoint MD */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)
{
    .hidden-md-down, .hidden-lg-down, .hidden-xl-down, 
    .hidden-xs-up, .hidden-sm-up, .hidden-md-up, 
    .hidden-unless-xs, .hidden-unless-sm, .hidden-unless-lg, .hidden-unless-xl
    {
        display: none !important;
    } 
}

/* Breakpoint LG */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)
{
    .hidden-lg-down, .hidden-xl-down, 
    .hidden-xs-up, .hidden-sm-up, .hidden-md-up, .hidden-lg-up, 
    .hidden-unless-xs, .hidden-unless-sm, .hidden-unless-md, .hidden-unless-xl
    {
        display: none !important;
    } 
}

/* Breakpoint XL */
@media (min-width: 1200px)
{
    .hidden-xl-down, 
    .hidden-xs-up, .hidden-sm-up, .hidden-md-up, .hidden-lg-up, .hidden-xl-up, 
    .hidden-unless-xs, .hidden-unless-sm, .hidden-unless-md, .hidden-unless-lg
    {
        display: none !important;
    } 
}
```

The classes `hidden-unless-*` were not included in Bootstrap 3, but they are useful as well and should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Does this still work with current version of B4? This visibility crap up is one of the main reasons I have not bothered moving. I get very befuddled sometimes when programming and this was just doing my head in. (I am 64 so give me a break!) Also (don't mean to be cheeky) but do you have an equivalent for visible? V useful to have both IMHO (or the way I code anyway :-) ) ATB Steve

Answer (score 31):

Bootstrap v4.1 uses new classnames for hiding columns on their grid system.

For hiding columns depending on the screen width, use `d-none` class or any of the `d-{sm,md,lg,xl}-none` classes.
To show columns on certain screen sizes, combine the above mentioned classes with `d-block` or `d-{sm,md,lg,xl}-block` classes.

Examples are:

```html
<div class="d-lg-none">hide on screens wider than lg</div>
<div class="d-none d-lg-block">hide on screens smaller than lg</div>
```

More of these [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements).

Answer (score 9):

## BOOTSTRAP 5

#### Hiding elements:

To hide elements simply use the `.d-none` class or one of the `.d-{sm,md,lg,xl,xxl}-none` classes for any responsive screen variation.

To show an element only on a given interval of screen sizes you can combine one `.d-*-none` class with a `.d-*-*` class, for example `.d-none .d-md-block .d-xl-none .d-xxl-none` will hide the element for all screen sizes except on medium and large devices.

| Screen size | Class |
| --- | --- |
| Hidden on all | `.d-none` |
| Hidden only on xs | `.d-none .d-sm-block` |
| Hidden only on sm | `.d-sm-none .d-md-block` |
| Hidden only on md | `.d-md-none .d-lg-block` |
| Hidden only on lg | `.d-lg-none .d-xl-block` |
| Hidden only on xl | `.d-xl-none .d-xxl-block` |
| Hidden only on xxl | `.d-xxl-none` |
| Visible on all | `.d-block` |
| Visible only on xs | `.d-block .d-sm-none` |
| Visible only on sm | `.d-none .d-sm-block .d-md-none` |
| Visible only on md | `.d-none .d-md-block .d-lg-none` |
| Visible only on lg | `.d-none .d-lg-block .d-xl-none` |
| Visible only on xl | `.d-none .d-xl-block .d-xxl-none` |
| Visible only on xxl | `.d-none .d-xxl-block` |

#### Display in print:

Change the display value of elements when printing with our print display utility classes. Includes support for the same display values as our responsive `.d-*` utilities.

- `.d-print-none`
- `.d-print-inline`
- `.d-print-inline-block`
- `.d-print-block`
- `.d-print-grid`
- `.d-print-table`
- `.d-print-table-row`
- `.d-print-table-cell`
- `.d-print-flex`
- `.d-print-inline-flex`

Comment: Adding my two cents, you can replace `.d-block` by `.d-flex` when using flexbox.

Answer (score 6):

For bootstrap 4, here's a matrix image explaining the classes used to show / hide elements depends on the screen size:
[image]

Source : [Meduim : Bootstrap 4 Hidden & Visible](https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-4-hidden-visible-dd969a4c5854)

Comment: Here is a live link from the Medium article on Codeply: https://www.codeply.com/embed/JFLPnkGxzA?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fwdstack%2Fbootstrap-4-hidden-visible-dd969a4c5854

Answer (score 4):

I do no expect that multiple div's is a good solution.

I also think you can replace `.visible-sm-block` with `.hidden-xs-down` and `.hidden-md-up` (or `.hidden-sm-down` and `.hidden-lg-up` to act on the same media queries).

`hidden-sm-up` compiles into:

```
.visible-sm-block {
  display: none !important;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .visible-sm-block {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

`.hidden-sm-down` and `.hidden-lg-up` compiles into:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .hidden-xs-down {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .hidden-lg-up {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Both situation should act the same.

You situation become different when you try to replace `.visible-sm-block` and `.visible-lg-block`. Bootstrap v4 docs tell you:

> These classes don’t attempt to accommodate less common cases where an
>   element’s visibility can’t be expressed as a single contiguous range
>   of viewport breakpoint sizes; you will instead need to use custom CSS
>   in such cases.

```
.visible-sm-and-lg {
  display: none !important;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .visible-sm-and-lg {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .visible-sm-and-lg {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The user Klaro suggested to restore the old visibility classes, which is a good idea. Unfortunately, their solution did not work in my project.

I think that it is a better idea to restore the old mixin of bootstrap, because it is covering all breakpoints which can be individually defined by the user.

Here is the code:

```
// Restore Bootstrap 3 "hidden" utility classes.
@each $bp in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  .hidden-#{$bp}-up {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($bp) {
      display: none !important;
    }
  }
  .hidden-#{$bp}-down {
    @include media-breakpoint-down($bp) {
      display: none !important;
    }
  }
  .hidden-#{$bp}-only{
    @include media-breakpoint-only($bp){
      display:none !important;
    }
  }
}
```

In my case, I have inserted this part in a `_custom.scss` file which is included at this point in the `bootstrap.scss`:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta (https://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2017 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2017 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "custom"; // <-- my custom file for overwriting default vars and adding the snippet from above
@import "print";
@import "reboot";
[..]
```

Comment: Very helpful! The Bootstrap 4 way seems to be a bit of a puzzle, plus that it's adding `display: block` which breaks flow in certain scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

You now have to define the size of what is being hidden as so

```
.hidden-xs-down
```

Will hide anythinging from xs and smaller, only xs

```
.hidden-xs-up
```

Will hide everything

Comment: Yes, I have used these in my v4 example, but the issue is I now need multiple DIVs where in v3 I could do with one...

Comment: This solution is out of date and is only valid for Bootstrap V4 Alpha, For Beta and after, unfortunately these need to be replaced as specified in above ocmments

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 to hide whole content use this class **'.d-none'** it will be hide everything regardless of breakpoints same like previous bootstrap version class **'.hidden'**

Answer (score 1):

Using the Bootstrap 5.3 version (which is the same for versions 4 and up) I found there to be a lack of very clear demonstrations so I [made the following](https://stackblitz.com/edit/g3q9xo?file=index.html).

Move the slider between the code and rendered site to see content show up:

- at exactly one page size
- when smaller than a certain page size
- when larger than a certain page size

Here's the good bit of code:

```
<div>Show at exactly one size:</div>
<div class="d-xs-block d-sm-none">XS</div>
<div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">SM</div>
<div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">MD</div>
<div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">LG</div>
<div class="d-none d-xl-block">XL</div>
<hr>
<div>Hide when smaller than size or show when larger than size:</div>
<div class="d-none d-xs-block">XS or larger</div>
<div class="d-none d-sm-block">SM or larger</div>
<div class="d-none d-md-block">MD or larger</div>
<div class="d-none d-lg-block">LG or larger</div>
<div class="d-none d-xl-block">XL or larger</div>
<hr>
<div>Hide when larger than size or show when smaller than size:</div>
<div class="d-sm-none">XS or smaller</div>
<div class="d-md-none">SM or smaller</div>
<div class="d-lg-none">MD or smaller</div>
<div class="d-xl-none">LG or smaller</div>
```

I hope that helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately these new bootstrap 4 classes do not work like the old ones on a div using `collapse` as they set the visible div to `block` which starts out visible rather than hidden and if you add an extra div around the `collapse` functionality no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

```
i like the bootstrap3 style as the device width of bootstrap4
so i modify the css as below
<pre>
.visible-xs, .visible-sm, .visible-md, .visible-lg { display:none !important; }
.visible-xs-block, .visible-xs-inline, .visible-xs-inline-block,
.visible-sm-block, .visible-sm-inline, .visible-sm-inline-block,
.visible-md-block, .visible-md-inline, .visible-md-inline-block,
.visible-lg-block, .visible-lg-inline, .visible-lg-inline-block { display:none !important; }
@media (max-width:575px) {
table.visible-xs                { display:table !important; }
tr.visible-xs                   { display:table-row !important; }
th.visible-xs, td.visible-xs    { display:table-cell !important; }

.visible-xs                 { display:block !important; }
.visible-xs-block { display:block !important; }
.visible-xs-inline { display:inline !important; }
.visible-xs-inline-block { display:inline-block !important; }
}

@media (min-width:576px) and (max-width:767px) {
table.visible-sm { display:table !important; }
tr.visible-sm { display:table-row !important; }
th.visible-sm,
td.visible-sm { display:table-cell !important; }

.visible-sm { display:block !important; }
.visible-sm-block { display:block !important; }
.visible-sm-inline { display:inline !important; }
.visible-sm-inline-block { display:inline-block !important; }
}

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
table.visible-md { display:table !important; }
tr.visible-md { display:table-row !important; }
th.visible-md,
td.visible-md { display:table-cell !important; }

.visible-md { display:block !important; }
.visible-md-block { display:block !important; }
.visible-md-inline { display:inline !important; }
.visible-md-inline-block { display:inline-block !important; }
}

@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
table.visible-lg { display:table !important; }
tr.visible-lg { display:table-row !important; }
th.visible-lg,
td.visible-lg { display:table-cell !important; }

.visible-lg { display:block !important; }
.visible-lg-block { display:block !important; }
.visible-lg-inline { display:inline !important; }
.visible-lg-inline-block { display:inline-block !important; }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
table.visible-xl { display:table !important; }
tr.visible-xl { display:table-row !important; }
th.visible-xl,
td.visible-xl { display:table-cell !important; }

.visible-xl { display:block !important; }
.visible-xl-block { display:block !important; }
.visible-xl-inline { display:inline !important; }
.visible-xl-inline-block { display:inline-block !important; }
}

@media (max-width:575px)                        { .hidden-xs{display:none !important;} }
@media (min-width:576px) and (max-width:767px)  { .hidden-sm{display:none !important;} }
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px)  { .hidden-md{display:none !important;} }
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) { .hidden-lg{display:none !important;} }
@media (min-width:1200px)                       { .hidden-xl{display:none !important;} }
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The hidden-* and visible-* classes no longer exist in Bootstrap 4. The same function can be achieved in Bootstrap 4 by using  the d-* for the specific tiers.