# Bootstrap: responsive utilities is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I expected this div:

http://www.bootply.com/yjJo9wg1Xa#

to be hidden when I press the mobile phone icon on the right.

Comment: as @Skelly said, you'll need Bootstrap 4. You can, however, use hidden-xs for earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

**Update Bootstrap 4:**

Bootstrap 4 hidden/visible see: [Missing visible-** and hidden-** in Bootstrap v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4/45844579#45844579)

**Original answer for Bootstrap 4 alpha:**

The Bootply is using Bootstrap 3. `hidden-md-down` is only available in Bootstrap 4:

Here's the Bootply with Bootstrap 4 utilities: http://www.bootply.com/G62VlzZq9t