# Bootstrap 4: hide medium only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've used Bootstrap 4 in a new online project of mine. I mainly aim at mobile use but want to make it accessible for desktop users.

I have some textst i'd like to hide on medium screens only with predefined classses, but somehow I can't get it to work. Sloppy workaround works but is sloppy: (should illustrate what I'm trying to achieve) :

`<span class="hidden-sm-up">Display: </span>`
`<span class="hidden-md-down">Display: </span>`

Of course this is bad coding, but I can't seem to find teh right combination of classes to only hide at medium screens. (I would expect a class like `.hidden-md` but no...)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
knal

Comment: .hidden-md should work according to the docs http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes

Comment: @Brad he is using bootstrap 4 not bootstrap 3

Comment: @neophyte; exactly why I encountered an unexpected 'inconsistency'.

Comment: Not supported in bootstrap 4 :(.. You have to add it with custom css :(

Comment: @knalpiap there no such class available in bootstrap 4.

Comment: this can be auseful link for you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4] mentioned by @Brad

Comment: I looks like the missing `hidden-md` and similar classes will be [back for the beta](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/22113) as `d-none-md`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys,

Slightly disappointed due to the lack of a straightformard solution but happy with the result I implemented the following to suit my needs:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 576px){  
    .filters p span {  
        display: none;
    }  
}
```

Brad's link convinced me of this method. Thanks!

Best,
Knal