# Change button group orientation vertical/horizontal with BS4 classes

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

How can I change the orient vertical/horizontal of a btn-group with bootstrap4 ONLY classes, I could not find any btn-group-vertical-xs , -md, -lg classes.

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure Bootstrap you would make a horizontal group and a vertical one, and toggle between them using [display classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/):

```html
<div class="btn-group d-none d-sm-block">
    <button class="btn">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 2</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group-vertical d-block d-sm-none">
    <button class="btn">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Note that the `hidden-*` and `visible-*` classes no longer exist in Bootstrap 4 Beta. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45844579/1563669) other answer for a conversion table.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `btn-group` is now `display: flexbox`, you can use `flex-column` class to make it vertical...

```
<div class="btn-group flex-column" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Right</button>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/Y3BVq9I49h

Comment: It seems you misunderstood me. My question is no how to make a btn-group vertically aligned items. For this I have btn-group-vertical :P I was asking to change the btn-group-vertical to horizontal under certain bootstrap sizes without using custom media queries.