# Bootstrap 4: Hidden Visible Cols?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I was wondering why the following isn't working - whereby xs is hidden in xs views. I feel it is something to do with changes introduced in Bootstrap v4, but I was wondering how this was still achievable within the code here than going into the CSS? I am using the default bootstrap.css file.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-xs col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    Some text here.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Adding this answer because the comments in the accepted answer are getting too long and it's not complete. As already explained, the `hidden-*` classes no longer exist in Bootstrap 4 beta.

*"What exactly is hidden-sm-DOWN?"*

It no longer exists in beta, but it previous versions it meant "hidden on small and down". Meaning, hidden on `xs` and `sm`, but otherwise visible.

If you want to hide an element on specific tiers (breakpoints) in Bootstrap 4, use the `d-*` display classes accordingly. Remember `xs` is the default (always implied) breakpoint, unless overridden by a *larger* breakpoint. Since `xs` is implied, you no longer use the `-xs-` infix. For example, it's not `d-xs-none`, it's simply `d-none`.

https://www.codeply.com/go/bRlHp8MxtJ

- `hidden-xs-down` = `d-none d-sm-block`
- `hidden-sm-down` = `d-none d-md-block`
- `hidden-md-down` = `d-none d-lg-block`
- `hidden-lg-down` = `d-none d-xl-block`
- `hidden-xl-down` = `d-none` (same as `hidden`)
- `hidden-xs-up` = `d-none` (same as `hidden`)
- `hidden-sm-up` = `d-sm-none`
- `hidden-md-up` = `d-md-none`
- `hidden-lg-up` = `d-lg-none`
- `hidden-xl-up` = `d-xl-none`
- `hidden-xs` (only) = `d-none d-sm-block` (same as `hidden-xs-down`)
- `hidden-sm` (only) = `d-block d-sm-none d-md-block`
- `hidden-md` (only) = `d-block d-md-none d-lg-block`
- `hidden-lg` (only) = `d-block d-lg-none d-xl-block`
- `hidden-xl` (only) = `d-block d-xl-none`
- `visible-xs` (only) = `d-block d-sm-none`
- `visible-sm` (only) = `d-none d-sm-block d-md-none`
- `visible-md` (only) = `d-none d-md-block d-lg-none`
- `visible-lg` (only) = `d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none`
- `visible-xl` (only) = `d-none d-xl-block`

[Demo of all hidden / visible classes in Bootstrap 4 beta](https://www.codeply.com/go/bRlHp8MxtJ)

Also note that `d-*-block` can be replaced with `d-*-inline`, `d-*-flex`, etc.. depending on the display type of the element. More on the [display classes in beta](https://medium.com/wdstack/upgrade-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-to-beta-ca582f15ee32)

---

Also see:
[Bootstrap 4 hidden-X-(down/up) class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839143/bootstrap-4-hidden-down-up-class-not-working/45839223#45839223)
[Missing visible-** and hidden-** in Bootstrap v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4/45844579)

Comment: This should be the correct answer! How can i remove mine and give it to you! +1.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**  the `hidden-*` properties are [removed from the bootstrap beta 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#responsive-utilities).

You need to use the `d-*-none` (*= xl, sm, md, lg). [Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#responsive-utilities)

For example:

the class `d-none` will allow you something to be invisible on every screen.

the class `d-sm-none`: will not be visible for small devices.

the class  `d-md-none`: will not be visbile for medium devices.

the class `d-lg-none`: will not be visbile for large screen devices devices.

For you, need to write this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        Some text here.
    </div>
</div>
```

Start with `d-none` add the screen that you want with `d-*-block`.
Example if you want to display for md only, you should write `class="d-none d-md-block"`.

Comment: For some reason, this still doesn't work for me. That was also the problem I was having.

Comment: Thank you Michael, that seems to be working for me too. 

Out of interest, do you know the usage of the "hidden-sm-up" and "-down" which is referenced as being in v4 now?

Comment: Have edited again! "hidden-sm-up" and "-down" are removed from v4 !  you should use d-*-none along with d-*-block.

Comment: Just so i'm clear too, and for anyone finding this in the future - d-none hides the div, d-'size here'-block shows it in that size view.

e.g <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-block col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> hides it in all but md and lg

If you agree?

Comment: yes, i think so i don't have a large screen to test!

Comment: Further [explained here](https://medium.com/wdstack/upgrade-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-to-beta-ca582f15ee32) `d-none d-md-block` is equivalent to `hidden-sm-down` so the `d-lg-block` is unnecessary.

Comment: @ZimSystem  What exactly is hidden-sm-DOWN? Previously I was using hidden-sm without the down/up - but unsure what this up/down refers to.

Comment: I think  hidden-sm-DOWN  means hide this div for devices that have "down" less that sm size. And Up: hide this div for devices that have "up" greater than sm size.

Comment: @ZimSystem I was hoping the following would work, but it doesn't appear to. In principle, I was asking if there was a neater way than just copy and pasting div classes, each of which appeared in different views:

  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="d-xs-block col-xs-12">
    <h5>This shows in xs view only!</h5>
    Sample Text
    </div>
    <div class="d-sm-block col-sm-12">
    <h5>This shows in sm view only!</h5>
    Sample Text
    </div>

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45842581/171456), and https://www.codeply.com/go/vEU45kUYZS