# Responsive show/hide classes in new Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling to understand how to implement the new classes that show and hide content relevant to screen size in Bootstrap 4

This doesn't seem to be working...

```
<div class="d-sm-block">
 ITEMS FOR SMALL/MOBILE DEVICES
</div>
<div class="d-md-block">
 ITEMS FOR  MEDIUM/LARGE DEVICES
</div>
```

Comment: These classes have completely changed in Bootstrap 4.0.0 _ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4

Answer (score 4):

There's no `d-sm-block` or `d-md-block`. You need to use the following classes:

[image: res]

See [Responsive Utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/) for the complete documentation.

**Your code should be:**

```
<div class="hidden-md-up">
 ITEMS FOR SMALL/MOBILE DEVICES
</div>
<div class="hidden-md-down">
 ITEMS FOR  MEDIUM/LARGE DEVICES
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Soolie  I got confused by [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#global-changes) saying  "Removed from v4 alphas: .hidden-xs-up .hidden-xs-down .hidden-sm-up .hidden-sm-down .hidden-md-up .hidden-md-down .hidden-lg-up .hidden-lg-down" - so the list you shared is still current?

Comment: actually no it doesn't @Soolie - they have been taken out of bootstrap 4 beta, as per this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4)