# hidden and visible bootstrap in breakpoints

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem using third version of Bootstrap:

My site has two main parts, side bar in left (blue) and main content in right (red). I want the sidebar to be invisible from 992px and up. I used the bottom code and just in 767px and 991px (breakpoints) it does not work well :(

```
<div 
  class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs sidebar" 
  style="height:200px ; background:blue">
</div>

<div
  class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 main"
  style="height:200px; background:red">
</div>
```

Comment: If you would consider Bootstrap v4, you will find classes taylored precisely to that need, see [the table here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

Comment: for v3, [this comparision table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45844579/444255) could be helpful.