# Bootstrap 4 visibility classes

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I wonder if someone could spare me a couple of minutes to tell me where I'm going wrong here. I'm trying to hide certain cells in a table under the new bootstrap 4 framework. Under version 3 I would have used hidden-xs.

```
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead class="hidden-xs">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" style="border-left: transparent 1px solid;border-top: transparent 1px solid;border-bottom: transparent 1px solid;"></th>
                       <th class="text-center hidden-xs">9</th>
                        <th class="text-center hidden-xs">10</th>
                        <th class="text-center hidden-xs">11</th>
                        <th class="text-center hidden-xs">12</th>
                        <th class="text-center hidden-xs">13</th>
                        <th class="text-center hidden-xs">14</th>
                        <th class="text-center hidden-xs">15</th>
                        <th class="text-center hidden-xs">16</th>
                        <th class="text-center hidden-xs">17</th>
                        <th class="text-center hidden-xs">18</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Score</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
           </table>
```

I've tried replacing hidden-xs with d-none d-sm-block but it has no effect. Stumped.

As a note the solutions offered in [Missing visible-** and hidden-** in Bootstrap v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4) unfortunately don't seem to work.

Thanks,
C

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest 4.0.0, and remember it would be `d-sm-table-cell` instead of `d-sm-block`! https://www.codeply.com/go/AqTysNwkTZ

Comment: The solutions offered in [Missing visible-** and hidden-** in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4) says "note that `d-*-block` can be replaced with `d-*-inline`, `d-*-flex`, etc.. depending on the display type of the element" which as I commented in your case is `d-none d-sm-table-cell`.