# How to show Navigation bar in Mobile View?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, responsive

I have developed Navigation bar using HTML and PHP.
But issue is that I can see Navigation bar in desktop and laptop but it can not be seen in mobile screen.

My code is look like this.

```
<header class="page__header media__img ratio--small">
        <?php include "navigation.php"; ?>

        <div class="nav--sub visible-sm">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_category_id" id="product_category_id" value="<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>">
            <ul>
                <?php
                $selectcategory = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from product_category where is_active='1' and is_delete='0'");

                while ($rowcategory = mysqli_fetch_array($selectcategory)) {

                    ?>
                    <li class="<?php if ($_GET['id'] == $rowcategory['product_category_id']) {
                        echo 'selected';
                    } ?>">
                        <a href="product_list.php?id=<?php echo $rowcategory['product_category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $rowcategory['product_category_name']; ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php

                }


                ?>

            </ul>
        </div>
     </header>
```

it perfectly works in large screen but not in Mobile devices.
Any bootstrap that make it visible to mobile devices.

**Laptop View**

[image: Laptop View]

**Mobile View**

[image: Mobile Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You included the tag bootstrap 4 in your question, but the `visible-sm` class is already replaced in bootstrap 4. If that's a custom css, do include it in your question.

The comparison between the old and new classes are mentioned here;
[Missing visible-** and hidden-** in Bootstrap v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4)

Try to use `visible-xs`;

```
<div class="nav--sub visible-xs">
...
</div>
```

Or `d-block d-sm-none`

```
<div class="nav--sub d-block d-sm-none">
...
</div>
```