# Rendering differences in Bootstrap 3 vs Bootstrap 4 Display Property classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am interested to learn whether there are rendering differences between Bootstrap 3 and 4 Display Classes, given there is a 1-to-1 mapping between the class names and no perceivable other differences. So I am ignoring why this has been done.

In Bootstrap 3 you could have a [Display Property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) like this:

```
<div class="hidden-xs">...</div>
```

In Bootstrap 4 the equivalent is:

```
<div class="d-none d-sm-block">...</div>
```

As far as I can tell, the rendered output from these 2 things is identical. So ignoring "why" the names have been changed, **is there any other difference between these two statements from a rendering perspective?** Or, do they do identical things?

[Missing visible-** and hidden-** in Bootstrap v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4) shows us that there is a 1-to-1 mapping between various Bootstrap 3 classes and the Bootstrap 4 equivalent.

Are they identical in terms of rendering or **do the additional class names in Bootstrap 4 provide other functionality**?

The linked post does not answer this question, because it says:

> The `hidden-*` and `visible-*` classes no longer exist in Bootstrap 4. If you want to hide an element on specific tiers or breakpoints in Bootstrap 4, use the `d-*` display classes accordingly.

It then goes on to show a 1-to-1 mapping for every Bootstrap 3 class name to the Bootstrap 4 equivalent. This does not confirm or deny whether there are *other differences* between what these display classes do in 4 vs 3. Therefore this is a legitimate question that needs a definitive answer.

Please be aware:

1. The proposed duplicate does not answer this question.
2. Many people use Bootstrap 3 and 4 - or are migrating from one version to another. Knowing the answer to this is useful as it helps ensure they are not changing rendering behaviour inadvertently.
3. The Bootstrap 3 (or 4) docs don't answer it.

Comment: I believe they are identical as all it does is change the elements CSS `display` attribute for different screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you, this is the most sensible response I've had to this question. I'm looking for confirmation. I also "believe" they are equivalent but that's what I'm trying to ascertain for certain.

Comment: I shall double check and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `hidden-xs` will just add `display: none !important`. You can look for youself in the minified version of Bootstrap 3 [here](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css).

Because Bootstrap 4 is different in the sense that it works from mobile first, so the class `d-none` does act slightly differently to that in Bootstrap 3.

The difference between the two is no more than a media query.

So to answer you question:

BS3's `hidden-xs` class adds `display: none !important;` just the same as `d-none` but because BS3 isn't mobile first, `hidden-xs` will only add that property when the view size is mobile (`<= 767px`). Whereas `d-none` will add the property on every screen size.

In order to get the same effect from `hidden-xs` in BS4 the equivilent would be `d-none d-sm-block`.

Read more about Bootstrap 4's display classes [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/).

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful and the information I was looking for. I believe this will be useful to other Bootstrap users and can't really understand why it was such a battle to get this question answered.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. I'm not entirely sure why people were closing your questions either, I think it's an entirely valid post.