# How do I not show the image or resize it when the screen size is smaller using bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
<td scope="row">
   <button className="btn btn-link " onClick={onUserClick}>
      <ProfileImageAndBasicInfo
         profileImageProps={profileImageAndBasicInfoProps.profileImageProps}
         basicInfoProps={profileImageAndBasicInfoProps.basicInfoProps}>
   </button>
```

I have tried using bootstrap to `button className` but it only works when using `d-none` but this hides the whole content. I just want to show the `basicInfoProps` when the screen is `xs`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4

Comment: Hey, thanks, but where do I write the bootstrap?

Comment: So change the ProfileImageAndBasicInfo to render that way