# How can i use differents span for computer and mobile?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, element-plus

I want to use :span="5" for computer

```
 <el-col :span="5" class="container">
```

and for mobile i want to use

```
 <el-col  class="container">
```

o how can i use sm, md, lg?

Comment: What is span on a column (div)? What is `el-col`? I don't recognize this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use media queries, and display or hide them depending on screen size.

```
<el-col :span="5" class="container hide-mobile">
<el-col  class="container show-mobile">


@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    .show-mobile {
        display:block;
    }
    .hide-mobile {
        display:none;
    }
}

.hide-mobile {
    display:block;
}

.show-mobile {
    display:none;
}
```

This would display the first element as a block by default, setting it to none on mobile screen sizes.

The second element would be hidden by default, and show as a block on mobile.

Comment: can i use directly sm, md, lg?

Comment: @signup You would use them like:
<el-col :span="5" :xs="8" :md="6" :lg="3"> 
Etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can make more than on div and make certain divs visible or not for the sizes, look at :

[Missing visible-** and hidden-** in Bootstrap v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4)

Or you can use jquery or javascrript to change items for different sizes but its easier using the above method.